# "to have" as in "I've had st. done"

Tags: single-word-request

The specific context is this:

> I've had the letter sent to my ouma.¹

Here are some other examples:

> · I've had the car cleaned.
>
> · The king had him executed.
>
> · She had the man sacked.

In all these cases, the subject is not the one who actually did the sending, cleaning, executing or sacking – they've given instructions to someone else to do it.

Can you use *haben* for this, or is there another word altogether? (Or must I rephrase?)

---

¹⋅ ˢʰᵉ'ˢ ˢᵒᵘᵗʰ ᴬᶠʳᶦᶜᵃᶰ, ˢᵒ ᶦᵗ'ˢ ᴬᶠʳᶦᵏᵃᵃᶰˢ⋅

Answer (score 3, accepted):

German doesn't have a "to have something done" construct that uses *haben*.

Sentences that are built like your examples are constructed using *lassen* + infinitive in German:

> Ich habe den Brief an meine Oma schicken lassen
>
> Ich habe das Auto putzen lassen
>
> Der König ließ ihn hinrichten
>
> Sie ließ den Mann entlassen

Comment: Der Darstellung des lexikalischen Prinzips pflichte ich bei. Jedoch frage ich mich, ob die deutschen Übertragungen mit *lassen* immer kontext-angemessen sind. Deckt sich die Gelegenheit der Verwendung von *She had the man sacked* genau mit der von *Sie ließ den Mann entlassen*? Oder ist es in diesem Fall nicht eher doch: "Sie entließ den Mann"? (Vielleicht auch nur weil "entlassen lassen" mir etwas ungewöhnlich doppelmoppelig vorkommt?)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann *she had the man sacked* - hat sie bestimmt nicht selbst getan. Von daher ist das Konstrukt mit "lassen" unabdingbar. Dass um deutschen Satz damit dann zweimal "lassen" vorkommt, ist eben Pech... Wenn dir das nicht gefällt, mußt du statt "entlassen" halt "feuern"  oder "kündigen" nehmen.

Comment: i**h**n hinrichten.

Comment: @Janka dankö, repariert

Comment: "Sie ließ den Mann entlassen" ist jedenfalls stilistisch unschön. Wenn sie ihn nicht selbst entlassen hat, würde eine Formulierung wie "Sie sorgte dafür, dass der Mann entlassen wurde" vorziehen.

Comment: @RHa "dafür sorgen, dass etwas geschieht" und "etwas machen lassen" können zwei verschiedene Dinge sein. Das zweitere erfordert in jedem Fall Autorität, das erstere nicht unbedingt.